# Rank(AB)=Rank(A) if and only if Null Space (A) ∩ Image(B)={0}

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

For any matrices A and B of conformable dimensions. I think I got the "if" part, but I'm stuck in the "only if". I tried a counterpositive argument but I failed to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A$ and $B$ as linear maps say $\phi_A$ and $\phi_B$ respectively. Say that $\phi_A : F^n \rightarrow F^m$ and $\phi_B : F^m \rightarrow F^p$. Then you can apply the dimension theorem to $\phi_B$ restricted to $\phi_A(F^n)$. This gives $$dim(\phi_B |_{\phi_A(F^n)}) = dim(N(\phi_B |_{\phi_A(F^n)})) + dim(R(\phi_B |_{\phi_A(F^n)}))$$
$$dim(N(\phi_B |_{\phi_A(F^n)})) = dim(N(\phi_A)  \cap  R(\phi_B)) + dim(R(\phi_A\phi_B)$$

So in particular 
$$dim(R(\phi_A\phi_B))  = dim(R(\phi_B |_{\phi_A(F^n)})) - dim(N(\phi_A)  \cap  R(\phi_B))  $$

Therefore 
$$Rank(AB) = Rank(A)- \underbrace{dim(N(A) \cap R(B))}_{0}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am having a hard time figuring out where the missing parenthesis should be. Also, as A and B are conformable to the AB multiplication, don't we need the range of B to be the same as the domain of A?. I also do not understand how the second inequality is deduced. Thanks again.